# pdf.js plugin works on web/localhost and how about local machine?

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

PDF.js (web-canvas-pdf rendering plugin) works fine with web/localhost and seems not working in local machine. My project has to be delivered in DVDs. So, will it not work at all in local-machine/DVDs? or is there any workaround to make pdf.js plugin work with local-machine from DVDs?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the browser. Check out the [README](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/README.md) from github.

From the section labeled "Getting the code":

> you need to start a local web server as some browsers don't allow
>   opening PDF files for a file:// url.

If you can include Python on the DVD, then you could run a webserver with

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```